# how to reduce resident memory size in weblogic server

Tags: server, weblogic

i am monitoring weblogic server using jconsole tool. i found there is no memory leak in the heap. but i see resident memory size is growing very high and it is not coming down eventhough heap comes under 1GB. I have 6GB of heap size and 12GB of RAM. single java process is holding most of the memory. I am using weblogic9 and jdk1.5.

Once the server is restarted memory is coming down and again it started growing and reaching maximum within low time span.

-xms1024m -xmx6144m

Can someone help in resolving this issue?..Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be seeing memory leak. Best option would be to set -xms2048m -xmx2048m and enable gc logging. Even after Full GC if memory is not getting reclaimed then you may have Memory Leak issue

Comment: but only resident memory is not decreasing..heap is decreasing..is there any relation oh heap leakage with resident size